# Having difficulty getting multiple columns in HDF5 Table Data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdf5

I am new to hdf5 and was trying to store a DataFrame row into the hdf5 format. I was to append a row at different locations within the file; however, every time I append it shows up at an array in a single column rather than a single value in multiple columns.

I have tried both h5py and pandas and it seems like pandas is the better option for appending. Additionally, I have really been trying a lot of different methods. Truly, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is me sending an array multiple times into the hdf5 file.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.zeros((1,48), dtype = float)

columnName = ['Hello'+str(y) for (x,y), item in np.ndenumerate(data)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns =columnName)

file = pd.HDFStore('file.hdf5', mode = 'a', complevel = 9, comlib = 'blosc')
for x in range(0,11):
    file.put('/data', df, column_data = columnName , append = True, format = 'table')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [243]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
```

This seems to work fine:

```
In [247]: store.put('foo',df,append=True,format='table')                               
In [248]: store.put('foo',df,append=True,format='table')                               
In [249]: store.put('foo',df,append=True,format='table')                               
In [250]: store['foo']                                                                 
Out[250]: 
   Hello0  Hello1  Hello2  Hello3  Hello4  ...  Hello43  Hello44  Hello45  Hello46  Hello47
0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0

[3 rows x 48 columns]
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a difference betwen append and put/ what the difference is... But both seem to work.  Also, it seems to be creating a very large file (not with this pseudo code)... Are there any tips on compression techniques?   It seems that h5py is better for creating compressed data.  Pandas seems to generate a lot of extra metadata, or at least something that is taking up a lot of additional space.

Comment: ... there is this _i_table folder that is generated for each group. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: A dataframe has row and column indices, as well as other metadata.  But those should be small compared to the 2d values array.  M+N vs M*N

Comment: yeah for some reason this '_i_tables'  is taking up a lot of space in the file. It seems to be collecting statistics for each column of data

Comment: You've generated the table, I haven't.  What's in this `_i_table`?  Does the `i` stand for indexing?  The `table` format (as opposed to `fixed`) is supposed to be appendable and searchable.  Those extra capabilities probably come at a cost - both in time and space.